# using .live() to .autocomplete() won't fire on domchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

I have this autocomplete

```
    $( "#tags" )
                // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
                .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
                    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                })
                .autocomplete({
                    minLength: 2,
                    /*source: function( request, response ) {
                        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                        response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
                    },*/
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        $.getJSON( "json.php", {
                            term: extractLast( request.term )
                        }, response );
                    }
                    

/*all the options omitted*/
            });
```

Which works great on dom.ready, but if I dynamically remove and add again the same form, the autosuggest feature wont get enabled, so I thought about using .live() but its giving me the same behavior

```
 $( "#tags" )
                // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
                .live( "keydown", function( event ) {
                    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                })
                .autocomplete({
                    minLength: 2,
                    /*source: function( request, response ) {
                        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                        response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
                    },*/
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        $.getJSON( "json.php", {
                            term: extractLast( request.term )
                        }, response );
                    }
                    

/*all the options omitted*/
            });
```

shouldn't .live() handle the dom change?

Comment: a side note, [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is now deprecated, use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead.

Comment: `live()` is deprecated but it still works in the latest version (1.7.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use `on` (although `live` is still available).
And you may want to initialize the autocomplete upon the first keystroke:

```
$( document ).on( "keydown", "#tags", function( event ) {
    if ( $.type( $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ) ) == "undefined" ) {
        $( this ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON( "json.php", {
                    term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
            }
        });
    }
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Note: instead of `$( document ).on` it is preferrable to use the closest "#tags" parent which is always in the DOM (never is removed or reloaded). `document` is parent of all, and is always present, that's why it always works for `on`. But we should avoid attaching all event handlers in the `document`, if possible.

---

Also, what other users answered is correct. When you do:

```
$( '#tags' ).live( ... ).autocomplete( ... );
```

This is the same as:

```
$( '#tags' ).live( ... );
$( '#tags' ).autocomplete( ... );
```

It means: the `live` call is not attached to the `autocomplete` call.

---

Also, as other users answered, instead of the solution above, a better place to initialize the `autocomplete` would be in the AJAX success event handler, i.e., right AFTER the "#tags" element is included in the DOM:

```
$('div#something').load('new_content_from_server', function() {
    // the tags arrived! let's initialize the autocomplete
    $( '#tags' ).autocomplete( ... );
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please check this question.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586849/autocomplete-textbox-with-multiple-data-from-database-in-codeigniter-using-ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586849/autocomplete-textbox-with-multiple-data-from-database-in-codeigniter-using-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

The autocomplete plugin itself adds handlers directly to the element.  You should rebind the handler after loading the new elements.  Typically you'd do this in the callback of the handler that modifies the DOM.  Refactoring the code to a function (or an OO solution) that applies the handlers will help keep your code DRY.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the `keydown` using `live()` and that doesn´t change the behaviour of the `autocomplete` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation will not initialize plugins on newly created elements unless you specifically do the initialization inside of the delegated event handler. Here's how you can do it with your specific situation:

```
$("body").delegate("#tags:not('.ac')","focus",function(){
    $(this).addClass("ac").autocomplete({...});
}).delegate("#tags","keydown",function(event){
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely common for people to assume that since delegation methods work for event handling that they can simply use these delegation methods like on() or live or delgate() to invoke plugins and this won't work unless the plugin is built with delegation methods internally.

Typically you need to invoke the plugin whenever you change the DOM and need new html to resond to plgin code

Comment: can you please check this link.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586849/autocomplete-textbox-with-multiple-data-from-database-in-codeigniter-using-ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586849/autocomplete-textbox-with-multiple-data-from-database-in-codeigniter-using-ajax)